# How do you make an overlay fade out if your mouse doesn't move?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I currently am using the code below to make a div class `.overlay` fade in when hovering over a div...
It fades out when you're not hovering over it.
How could I also make it fade out if your pointer is stationary for "x" time?

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".img-holder").on("mouseenter", function(){
        $(".overlay").stop(true, true).fadeIn();
    });

    $(".img-holder").on("mouseleave", function(){
        $(".overlay").stop(true, true).fadeOut();
    });
}); 
</script>
```

Comment: stationary means at particular x,y position or anywhere on the div?

Comment: yes stationary anywhere inside the main div .img-holder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated with new requirements:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var timer = 0,
        idleThreshold = 1;

    setInterval(function(){
        if(timer > idleThreshold) {
            $('.overlay').stop(true, true).fadeOut();
        } else {
            timer++; }
    }, 1000);

    $('.img-holder').on("mousemove", function(){
        if(timer == 0) {
            $(".overlay").stop(true, true).fadeIn();
        }
        timer = 0;
    });

    $(".img-holder").on("mouseenter", function(){   
        $(".overlay").stop(true, true).fadeIn();    
    });

    $(".img-holder").on("mouseleave", function(){
        $(".overlay").stop(true, true).fadeOut();
    });  
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/brbcoding/7YHHe/1/)**

Comment: That seems to work, but how do you get it to fadeIn again without having to move the mouse completely outside of the div and back in again? Any way to make it fade back in on a movement within the div?

Comment: What # do I change to make the stationary interval 1 second?

Comment: This works great. I would recommend using `if(timer >= idleThreshold) {` instead of just `>` so that it executes in 1 second and not on the 2nd second (heh)

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:
setTimeout(function(){ 
    $(".img-holder").fadeOut("slow"); 
  }, 10000 );

Comment: That's not enough, you'd need to do it inside of a mousemove as well as clearing the timer on each event.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this too

```
var timer;
var x=3000; // in ms

$(document).on('mousemove', function () {
    clearTimeout(timer);

    timer = setTimeout(function () {
       $(".overlay").stop(true, true).fadeOut();
    }, x);
});
```